# данные из парсера не обновляются без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, ajax, парсер

есть парсер, который лежит в файле pars.php

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

   $url =('https://myfin.by/crypto-rates/bitcoin-rub');
   $file1 = file_get_html($url);
   $pars = $file1->find('.birzha_info_head_rates',1)->find('span',0);


    $result = substr($pars, 7, -8);
$pars2 = substr($pars, 6,-7);`
```

и есть ajax запрос, который лежит в файле index

```
<script>
        $("document").ready(function() {
            function get() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pars.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function() {
                        $('.p').text('<? echo $pars2?>');
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(function() {
                get();
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>
```

Проблема в том, что данные не обновляются при изменении их на сайте, с которого я и осуществляю парс, хотя из консоли я вижу что данные обновляются. В чем проблема? Спасибо

Comment: Проблема в том что вы не поняли как работает Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

pars.php

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url =('https://myfin.by/crypto-rates/bitcoin-rub');
$file1 = file_get_html($url);
$pars = $file1->find('.birzha_info_head_rates',1)->find('span',0);

$result = substr($pars, 7, -8);
$pars2 = substr($pars, 6,-7);
echo json_encode($pars2);
```

Скрипт аякса

```
<script>
        $("document").ready(function() {
            function get() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pars.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.p').text(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(function() {
                get();
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>
```